# What is the output of my ConvLSTM network in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

My input is a tensor of X_train.shape=(4291, 1, 278, 29, 1). My output is a tensor of Y_train.shape=(4291, 1, 9). When  it conducted fit(X_train,Y_train), it showed me an error of

> "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (4291, 1, 9)"

So how do I deal with the shape of output?

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=8, kernel_size=5, strides=2,
                   input_shape=(1, 278, 29, 1),activation='relu',
                   padding='same',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(9))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="Adam", metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your model has a shape of `(None, 9)`. Therefore, the target array (i.e. `Y_train`) must have the same shape, i.e. `(num_samples, 9)`. Try to reshape it:

```
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1, 9)  # -1 indicates that the dimension of that axis should be automatically inferred.
```